# Recursive setTimeout calls mysteriously stop running

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to call a function in JavaScript continuously, for example each 5 seconds until a cancel event.
I tried to use setTimeout and call it in my function

```
function init()
  {  setTimeout(init, 5000); 

  // do sthg
  }
```

my problem is that the calls stops after like 2 min and my program is a little bit longer like 5 min.

How can i keep calling my function as long as i want to.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you use `setInterval` ?

Comment: There is no apparent reason why that would stop working. The only reason that I can think of is if you assign something different to the `init` identifier, so that the function can't be called any more.

Comment: Is there any chance that something is happening to reload the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only conceivable explanations of the behavior you describe are that:

1. As another poster mentioned, `init` is somehow getting overwritten in the course of executing itself, in the `// do sthg` portion of your code
2. The page is being reloaded.
3. The `//do sthg` code is going into some kind of error state which makes it looks as if it not executing.

To guarantee that `init` is not modified, try passing the `// do sthg` part as a function which we will call `callback`:

```
function startLoop(callback, ms) {
    (function loop() {
        if (cancel) return;
        setTimeout(loop, ms);
        callback();
    }());
}
```

Other posters have suggested using `setInterval`. That's fine, but there's
nothing fundamentally wrong with setting up repeating actions using `setTimeout` with the function itself issuing the next `setTimeout` as you are doing. it's a common, well-accepted alternative to setting up repeating actions. Among other advantages, it permits the subsequent timeouts to be tuned in terms of their behavior, especially the timeout interval, if that's an issue. If the code were to be rewritten using `requestAnimationFrame`, as it probably should be, then there is no alternative but to issue the next request within the callback, because `requestAnimationFrame` has no `setInterval` analog.

Answer (score -1):

That function is called [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

```
var interval = setInterval(init, 5000);

// to cancel
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP question as to why his current code does not work.